# I'm looking for an elegant way to loop through vectors with multiple depths

Tags: c++

I created a sort of display tree with vectors. Objects in the tree might have children, and those children might have children too, the only thing is, I don't know how many...

I created a loop, inside a loop, inside a loop, inside a loop... is there an elegant way to avoid writing down too many loops?

```
for (unsigned int i =0; i< vectorTree.size(); i++){
    if (vectorTree[i].hasChildren){
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < vectorTree[i].children.size(); j++){
            if (vectorTree[i].children[j].hasChildren){
                for (unsigned int k = 0; k< 
                    vectorTree[i].children[j].children.size(); k++){
                        if (...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to find an elegant way to do this, I'm sure it's something experimented coders already know, I'm just that new :D

Comment: Maybe use recursion

Comment: If you know a depth of tree in advance and it is not big, using of c++ for_each loop could eliminate all redundant local variables. If this depth is unknown, I would prefer recursive traversal of tree: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: @NickMack please check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion to avoid writing too many loops.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void print_multidimensional_vector(std::vector<int> const& vec) {
    for (auto item : vec) {
        std::cout << item << " ";
    }
}

template <typename T>
void print_multidimensional_vector(T const& vec) {
    for (auto item : vec) {
        print_multidimensional_vector(item);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> vec = {
        {
            {
                1, 2, 3
            },
            {
                4, 5, 6
            }
        },
        {
            {
                7, 8, 9
            },
            {
                10, 11, 12
            }
        }
    };

    print_multidimensional_vector(vec);

    return 0;
}
```

And the output is: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12`

Answer (score 0):

thanks again for your valuable help guys ! 
Here's what I came up with after some playing around:

```
Sprite stage;

int main(){

    recursiveFinder(stage);
    return 0;
}

void  Stage::recursiveFinder(Sprite * _sprite)
{
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<_sprite->_children.size(); i++)
    {
        renderWindow.draw(_sprite->_children[i]->sprite);
        if (_sprite->_children[i]->hasChildren){
            recursiveFinder(_sprite->_children[i]);
        }
    }
}
```